# Reusable templates for common display elements (tables, etc.) in django

Tags: django, templates

I'm building a django application that has similar-looking display elements on several different pages.

For example, the projects.html page has a table that lists projects and some related information; the documents.html page has a similar-looking table

It seems like there ought to be a way to define a "my_kind_of_table" template and then insert it into different pages as necessary:

```
{% proj_list | create_my_kind_of_table:name,description,last_update %}
```

and then...

```
{% doc_list | create_my_kind_of_table:name,header,owner %}
```

I suspect that django can already do this, but I don't know what to search for. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`{% include ... %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include)?

To add context variables that all tables needs, then you have three solutions to pick: One is what I would call the "old fashioned" way, and is to have special function that is called by all views that needs to add context function. The second is to create a function decorator, that is used on the function that returns the response. The third way can be used if you use the new 1.3 class-based views, then you can create a mixin-class that your view-class inherits, and that adds these things in its own `get` method.

Answer (score 1):

Custom template tags and filters will accomplish this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: This looks like overkill for what I'm doing, but the reference is handy.  thanks